# How can I pass environment variables from a Dockerfile to a Vue 3 app with Vite?

Tags: dockerfile, environment-variables, vuejs3, vite

I'm building an Vue 3 app with vite. I will run this in a docker container, i'm trying to pass env variables from my dockerfile to the app so i can use them in the code.

Dockerfile:

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

ARG VITE_API_URL_ARG=http://localhost:8080
ENV VITE_API_URL=$VITE_API_URL_ARG

RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]


UPDATE:
Added .env file in the root.
Added the variable VITE_API_URL in the .env file:
VITE_API_URL=https://url

Trying to get the value with console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL); inside my own created component.
Ends up in the console "undefined"
This is when i'm running locally.

Using 
vue version: "^3.2.47", vite version: "^4.3.4"

Cheers!
```

Comment: Have u tried env file and it worked?

Comment: You mean a .env file? How will i then pass the env variable from the dockerfile? @testing_22

Comment: I mean if you tried recognizing environment variables without docker, with an .env file from your local machine. To understand if the problem is with docker or not

Comment: I just tested, still ends up "undefined" :( @testing_22

Comment: So its with vite maybe? What versions of the lib and OS are u using? In my project I had a similar problem but solved recently

Comment: I'm using: "vue": "^3.2.47", "vite": "^4.3.4", ah okey cool, yea i think its something with vite as well. let me know if u want any more info. ty! @testing_22

Comment: Well, I'm using an older version of Vite "^3.2.0". However, it recognizes the env variable automatically outside the vite.config.js

Comment: You need to create a variable prefixed with VITE an then use it in your code. For example in .env: "VITE_API_URL=localhost" and call this variable on index.js. Don't need the `define: {
    'process.env': {
      VITE_API_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.VITE_API_URL),
    },
  },

Comment: Ah okey, i will try this, then u use the import.meta.env syntax? "and call this variable on index.js" can i use the variable in a own created component? or do you need to add them to index.ts? thanks! @testing_22

Comment: You can use this syntax in your own component. Read more here: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files